# Using external jars for pojos in drl using Drools 5

Tags: drools

I'm a newbie to Drools - i'm creating an application that uses drl files but my model is in a separate jar.  When I reference the pojos locally in the drl it works fine, but when I put the pojos in a separate jar, it fails with a runtime exception complaining that's it's uncompilable code.  Is there any way to reference pojos from the drl file that are in another jar?

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing this in my project.
You can use a [BRMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_rule_management_system), like [Drools Guvnor](http://www.jboss.org/drools/drools-guvnor.html).

There, you can upload you jar with your model, so your *.drl can use them.

Or, you can just copy the model jar to the folder that have drl files (your package).